# Multi-tiered MVC Web App - updating the UI on status

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a blank slate project that will be replacing our use of Access Databases, which were largely used to perform some analysis on input files and output a new file.

We want to proceed with a web app, and I have pretty much free reign, but I do want to get this done quickly. However, I don't want to be sloppy and am trying to (as carefully as I can) plan out the architecture for this so that it is scalable.

Essentially, I am creating a multi-tiered MVC application, with the MVC5 project being more or less the presentation layer, and separate projects for BusinessLogic, BusinessObjects, and the Data layer.

I expect the MVC controllers to just send information to the business logic layer, where the real work is performed. I want to be sure then that the business logic layer can communicate back to the UI when necessary - ideally I'd like to return messages as things happen, such as when a file is being processed - I'd like to pop a message up and say that processing is done and it's starting the next step, for example.

This seems easily doable if I was doing the processing with JavaScript, but the processing is done on the server side.

Is there a way to have the Business Logic layer call the controller or otherwise push messages up to the UI?

Comment: you could use events to push things around the C# code, and websockets to communicate with the browser. Or write progress into a job status table in the DB and have the browser make an ajax call to a controller method which just polls the status table every minute or so. Depends how long your job takes. Also consider handing off the processing to a background service if it's going to take more than 30 seconds or so, otherwise the HTTP request which launched the task will probably time out.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I would typically make tasks for things like this. I'll have to look into using web sockets and events for this - not something I'm familiar with. Thanks!